# How do I load a sql.gz file to my database? (importing)

Tags: mysql, database, gzip, import

I'm trying to import a gzipped SQL file into mysql directly. Is this the right way?

```
mysql -uroot -ppassword mydb > myfile.sql.gz
```

Comment: Even ignoring the gzip side of the question, your arrow is pointing the wrong way...

Answer (score 389, accepted):

```
zcat /path/to/file.sql.gz | mysql -u 'root' -p your_database
```

`>` will write the output of the `mysql` command on `stdout` into the file `myfile.sql.gz` which is most probably not what you want. Additionally, this command will prompt you for the password of the MySQL user "root".

Comment: As a good security practice, I would put my password on the command line, I would let mysql ask for it.

Comment: Or even better: create `~/.my.cnf` with the credentials. ;)

Comment: As @Prof. Moriarty explans, you can modify the command to not use the password via `zcat /path/to/file.sql.gz | mysql -u 'root' -p your_database`. It will know the last parameter is the database you wish to use, not your password.

Comment: To slightly correct @Prof.Moriarty's comment, a good security practice would be to *not* put my password on the command line (where it will get stored in history, or seen over your shoulder), and let MySQL ask for it. The -p flag alone will cause MySQL to ask at a prompt for the password.

Comment: Good point. I have updated the original answer.

Comment: How would you include some additional SQL e.g. to disable foreign key checks before the file?

Comment: +1 for something that leaves the damn database dump compressed

Comment: If you run into issues with `zcat` you may also try `gzcat`. On my MacBook I ran into the error: `zcat: can't stat: file.sql.gz (file.sql.gz.Z): No such file or directory`

Comment: This chokes on mac because for whatever reason, OSX always appends a `.Z` to the file name. You can use `gunzip -c` in place of `zcat` though and it works fine.

Comment: Hi. From a performance point of view, is it faster to import the dump from the one-liner way? Or is it faster to uncompress to file.sql, then import? Thank you in advance for your opinion.

Comment: @DarkCowboy That depends on whether your CPU, your disk I/O, or the database I/O (which might be a combination of the previous two) is the bottleneck.

Comment: It would be nice if they created `sourcegz` mysql command.

Comment: Any GUI tools for this purpose?

Comment: `pv file.sql.gz |zcat| mysql -u 'root' -p your_database` to see progress

Comment: my database is about `10 GB` (data+index) and the .gz file is about `1.5 GB`. how long may this process of importing take?

Comment: @Soheil there’s no way one can answer that question without knowing the format of your data and the tech specs of your server.

Comment: @bfontaine yes! more data was needed to make a judgement. I was using 24GB RAM, 6 core CPU and my tables had many indices, it took about 5 hours!

Comment: if you need to edit the SQL dump first (for example for upgrading SQL versions) you can also use `zcat /path/to/file.sql.gz > /path/to/temp_dump.sql`, make edits, and then `cat  /path/to/temp_dump.sql | mysql -u 'root' -p your_database`

Answer (score 127):

To display a progress bar while importing a sql.gz file, download `pv` and use the following:

```
pv mydump.sql.gz | gunzip | mysql -u root -p <database name>
```

In CentOS/RHEL, you can install pv with `yum install pv`.

In Debian/Ubuntu, `apt-get install pv`.

In macOS, `brew install pv`

In Amazon Linux2, `sudo amazon-linux-extras install epel`
and then `sudo yum install pv`

Comment: `pv` seems to be in the Ubuntu repos too (at least in 12.04 LTS it is), but again you need to do `sudo apt-get install pv` to get it. Thanks Banjer, this is perfect for big database imports!

Comment: I had to run pv mydump.sql.gz | gunzip | mysql -u root my_database_name. That was because I was importing tables and I don't have a password set for my root user

Comment: In MAC, `brew install pv`

Comment: Great answer! I had to import huge database (3GB compressed, 50GB plaintext) and having progress bar really helped

Answer (score 74):

The simplest way is to unzip the database file before importing.  Also [as mentioned by @Prof. Moriarty](https://serverfault.com/questions/137965/how-do-i-load-a-sql-gz-file-to-my-database-importing/333721#comment117322_137966) you shouldn't be specifying the password in the command (you'll be asked for the password). This command taken from [webcheatsheet](http://www.webcheatsheet.com/SQL/mysql_backup_restore.php#restore) will unzip and import the database in one go:

```
gunzip < myfile.sql.gz | mysql -u root -p mydb
```

Comment: Also, mydb needs to be created before importing.  This doesn't create the db for you.

Comment: i found my piping `gunzip` on a 10GB compressed file caused my import to freeze. not sure if that's due to memory constraints or something but i'd err on the side of doing one step at a time in the future.

Comment: @RyanTuck That is pushing the limits of these kind of processes :)

Comment: @Siddhartha That depends on the sql dump file. Sometimes they include create database statements.

Comment: @rooby that makes sense.

Answer (score 20):

If you get an error from `zcat`, in which the error message contains the file name with an extra suffix `.Z`, then try using `gzcat` instead, as described at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/296717/zcat-wont-unzip-files-properly

Answer (score 7):

On macOS, I used this:

```
zcat < [Database].sql.gz | mysql -u root -p [Database Name in MySQL]
```

Enter your password, and voila!

Comment: Obviously you don't need the < sign because zcat is using directed input already. But this works beautifully.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `-c, --stdout, --to-stdout` option of `gunzip` command

for example:

```
gunzip -c file.sql.gz | mysql -u root -p database
```

Answer (score 4):

Also check if there is any USE-statement in the SQL file. Specifying the database at the command line doesn't guarantee that the data ends up there if a different destination is specified within the SQL file.

Comment: You just need to extend the command like so: `pv mydump.sql.gz | gunzip | mysql -u root -p` `your_database`. The accepted answer uses this approach.

Answer (score 4):

If you are using small size database it's better to extract and import.
Here is the extract command

```
tar -xf dbname.sql.tar.gz
```

Here is importing command.

```
mysql -u username -p new_database < data-dump.sql
```

Answer (score 3):

On **MacOS** I've been using the following one-liner with no need of installing additional programs, except for the MySQL client itself.

```
$ cat /path/to/file.sql.gz | gzip -d | mysql -u root <db_name>
```

The first command, `cat`, prints the file. Its output, the file contents, is sent as the input to the next command, `gzip`. `gzip` with the the `-d` option decompresses the input passed to it and outputs the result, which is finally used as input for the MySQL client, the `mysql` program. The output -> input sending is brought to us by the `|` (pipe) operator on bash and other shell.

This script can also be used in some popular Linux distros, such as Ubuntu. I'm not sure whether `gzip` is always available. But it can be easily installed, if not, with:

```
$ sudo apt install gzip
```

Answer (score 1):

For **bzip2** compressed files (.sql.bz2), use:

```
bzcat <file> | mysql -u <user> -p <database>
```

OR

```
pv <file> | bunzip2 | mysql -u <user> -p <database>
```

to see progress bar.

Answer (score 1):

To export in `.sql.qz` command is :-

```
mysqldump -u username -p  database | gzip   >  database.sql.gz
```

To import the `.sql.qz` file command is:-

```
gunzip <  database.sql.gz  | mysql -u usrname -p newdatabase
```

Answer (score 0):

Lets say you need to populate user_data with mysql, try this:

```
export DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive \
    apt-get update -yq
    dpkg -l | grep mysql-server || (echo "Installing MySQL..." \
    && apt-get install -yq mysql-server \
    && echo -e "\n[mysqld]\nbind-address=0.0.0.0\nskip-name-resolve=1" | tee -a /etc/mysql/my.cnf \
    && aws s3 cp --quiet s3://your-bucket/mysqldump_all_databases.sql.gz - | zcat | mysql -uroot\
    && systemctl restart mysql)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are a **windows** user, I recommend you follow these steps:

1. The first step is to install gzip, I recommend you do it using **Chocolatey**. You can install it via the following link: https://chocolatey.org/install
2. After cholocatey installed, now just install gzip:

   `choco install gzip -y`
3. Once installed, you can now unzip and import your sql.gz files directly into the MySQL prompt with the following command in command prompt *(cmd.exe)*:

   `gzip -cd backup.sql.gz | mysql -uUSER -pPASSWORD -hLOCALHOST DATABASE`

Notes and useful:

- If you want to dump and compress it directly using gzip, just do it using the command below:

  `mysqldump -uUSER -pPASSWORD -hHOSTNAME DATABASE_NAME | gzip -a9 > PATH_TO_SAVE_FILE_SQL_GZ`
- The `-h` parameter in `mysqldump` does not require for using in localhost. Use this for remote MySQL server
- Use in `gzip` the `-9` parameter to the best compression level or `-1` parameter to fast compression.